# when i user firebase-core and click pub get . I face a below problem . how can I solve this problem

Tags: android, flutter

Because flutter_app1111 depends on firebase_core >=0.8.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: upgrade your flutter version and reopen your ide

Answer (score 0):

change that line in pubspec.yaml file to the following:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Also in your terminal run `flutter upgrade`